# How to export my iPhone's step count?

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

On my iPhone 11 running ios 16, the Health app shows me the current day's step count or a bar chart for the past week or month. How can I export the data to my PC for use in a spreadsheet?

Just to be clear, I don't have an Apple Watch; I'm asking about the steps recorded by my iPhone.